# How to convert an XYZ file to Z-matrix?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, cheminformatics

I would like to generate a Z-matrix from the following XYZ file (`C2H6dimer.xyz`):

```
16
C2H6dimer
C    0.539202   -0.539202    1.933833
C   -0.539202    0.539202    1.933833
H    1.536064   -0.098299    1.932264
H    0.459532   -1.174264    2.816008
H    0.456405   -1.179449    1.055941
H   -1.536064    0.098299    1.932264
H   -0.459532    1.174264    2.816008
H   -0.456405    1.179449    1.055941
C    0.539202    0.539202   -1.933833
C   -0.539202   -0.539202   -1.933833
H    1.179449    0.456405   -1.055941
H    1.174264    0.459532   -2.816008
H    0.098299    1.536064   -1.932264
H   -1.174264   -0.459532   -2.816008
H   -0.098299   -1.536064   -1.932264
H   -1.179449   -0.456405   -1.055941
```

However I can't do it with the Gaussian utility called `newzmat`, because after typing `newzmat -ixyz C2H6dimer.xyz -ozmat`, I receive the following error message:

```
 Error in cartesian coordinates.
  WANTED A FLOATING POINT NUMBER AS INPUT.
  FOUND AN END-OF-LINE FOR INPUT.
 16
   ?
 Error termination via Lnk1e at Sun Jun 21 01:09:30 2020.
Segmentation fault
```

Could you please help me to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Please include anything that is a prerequisite to create the problem. Am I right to assume that the program newzmat is a utility of Gaussian (which version)?

Comment: Can you try to remove the last (empty) line? Gaussian can be very strict about empty lines in places it does not expect them. Maybe `newzmat` behaves similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the manual of the `newzmat` utility of Gaussian 16, it accepts unadorned Cartesian coordinates ([G16 online manual](https://gaussian.com/newzmat/?tabid=1)). The format you have posted is actually (simple) `xmol`. This means the first line denotes the number of atoms, the second line denotes a comment, and both need to be skipped.

Therefore your file should look like this:

```
C    0.539202   -0.539202    1.933833
C   -0.539202    0.539202    1.933833
H    1.536064   -0.098299    1.932264
H    0.459532   -1.174264    2.816008
H    0.456405   -1.179449    1.055941
H   -1.536064    0.098299    1.932264
H   -0.459532    1.174264    2.816008
H   -0.456405    1.179449    1.055941
C    0.539202    0.539202   -1.933833
C   -0.539202   -0.539202   -1.933833
H    1.179449    0.456405   -1.055941
H    1.174264    0.459532   -2.816008
H    0.098299    1.536064   -1.932264
H   -1.174264   -0.459532   -2.816008
H   -0.098299   -1.536064   -1.932264
H   -1.179449   -0.456405   -1.055941
```

In Gaussian terms, a block of cartesian coordinates is also a z-matrix. Therefore you also need to tell Gaussian to rebuild it (`-rebuildzmat`). This will likely fail on your input with an error:

> Input z-matrix variables are not compatible with final structure.

If you allow rounding (`-round`) it will work. The complete command is:

```
newzmat -ixyz -ozmat -round -rebuildzmat <input.xyz> <output.com>
```

The following file is produced (it is a valid Gaussian input file):

```
# HF/6-31G* Test

-- No Title Specified --

 0,1
 C
 C,1,R2
 H,1,R3,2,A3
 H,1,R4,2,A4,3,D4,0
 H,1,R5,2,A5,3,D5,0
 H,2,R6,1,A6,3,D6,0
 H,2,R7,1,A7,6,D7,0
 H,2,R8,1,A8,6,D8,0
 C,3,R9,1,A9,2,D9,0
 C,9,R10,3,A10,1,D10,0
 H,9,R11,3,A11,10,D11,0
 H,9,R12,3,A12,10,D12,0
 H,9,R13,3,A13,10,D13,0
 H,10,R14,9,A14,3,D14,0
 H,10,R15,9,A15,14,D15,0
 H,10,R16,9,A16,14,D16,0
      Variables:
 R2=1.53
 R3=1.09
 R4=1.09
 R5=1.09
 R6=1.09
 R7=1.09
 R8=1.09
 R9=4.04
 R10=1.53
 R11=1.09
 R12=1.09
 R13=1.09
 R14=1.09
 R15=1.09
 R16=1.09
 A3=111.
 A4=111.
 A5=111.
 A6=111.
 A7=111.
 A8=111.
 A9=81.
 A10=94.
 A11=22.
 A12=128.
 A13=104.
 A14=111.
 A15=111.
 A16=111.
 D4=120.
 D5=-120.
 D6=180.
 D7=120.
 D8=-120.
 D9=-76.
 D10=-21.
 D11=-144.
 D12=-120.
 D13=113.
 D14=167.
 D15=120.
 D16=-120.

 1 2 1.000 3 1.000 4 1.000 5 1.000
 2 1 1.000 6 1.000 7 1.000 8 1.000
 3 1 1.000
 4 1 1.000
 5 1 1.000
 6 2 1.000
 7 2 1.000
 8 2 1.000
 9 10 1.000 11 1.000 12 1.000 13 1.000
 10 9 1.000 14 1.000 15 1.000 16 1.000
 11 9 1.000
 12 9 1.000
 13 9 1.000
 14 10 1.000
 15 10 1.000
 16 10 1.000
```

Whether or not this z-matrix does actually fits the purpose you are needing it for, is a different question. For the most tasks, where z-matrices are the superior input, I recommend building it by hand.

Answer (score 2):

I copied and pasted your XYZ into [this](https://www.webqc.org/molecularformatsconverter.php) and got the Z-matrix for your XYZ coordiantes (see below). Geoff Hutchison's comment points out that this uses OpenBabel. Here is a ZMAT for your XYZ coordinates:

```
16
C   1
C   1 1.525
H   1 1.090  2 111.141
H   1 1.090  2 111.120  3 119.9
H   1 1.090  2 111.206  3 239.9
H   2 1.090  1 111.141  3 179.8
H   2 1.090  1 111.120  3 299.7
H   2 1.090  1 111.206  3  59.7
C   8 3.216  2 130.964  1  32.0
C   9 1.525  8  85.518  2  56.3
H   9 1.090  8  56.495  2 297.1
H   9 1.090  8 161.358  2 262.3
H   9 1.090  8  72.021  2 170.2
H  10 1.090  9 111.120  8 129.0
H  10 1.090  9 111.141  8 248.9
H  10 1.090  9 111.206  8   9.1
```

***In my experience, this is the fastest and easiest way to to convert an XYZ file to Z-matrix format, except maybe in extremely difficult cases***.

Comment: Incidentally, this uses [Open Babel](https://openbabel.org/) behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in Avogadro Molecular Editor and Visualizer that you can download freely.

1. Open your .xyz file in Avogadro. Click on the extensions in the top.
   [image]
2. In the extensions, select Gaussian. This opens a guassian input editor like below.
   [image]
3. Change the format to Z-matrix or Z-matrix (compact), whichever one you like.
   [image]

This editor has a nice interface that you can use to edit your Gaussian input.

Comment: Incidentally, this also uses Open Babel behind the scenes.